# Not able to add column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, mdf

I have project which contain 4 tables among these shedule table Session column i am not able to add vaue,,this table contain

three foriegn key from two tables(in which single table has two foreign keys here) i added values here..Any one 
has any idea about this..Actually my intention is to remove the error "the insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint sql server"

**Table Shedule contains session number as primary key,,it is used as foreign key in Q&A table.Table Q&A contains Question num
as primary key .Table Employee contain Employeeid as primary key  which is used as foriegn key in Q&A table two times foriegn 
key as in Shedule table .Table Topic contain Topicid as primary key which is used forign key in Shedule table ans Q&A table
Here my problem is i cant add values for session column in Shedule table(which is a primary key)
second is whenever i insert values in Q&A table i am getting error like this
Error Message: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_QandA_Schedule". The conflict occurred in database "secon", table "dbo.Schedule", column 'Session_No'.
The statement has been terminated.**

Comment: Can you provide some table schema? It sounds like you are trying to insert a value into one of the foreign key columns that does not already exist in the parent table.

Comment: But before that i am not able to add a single value in column Session in shedule table which is a primary key ,,is there any
settings i do here

Comment: check the log, the child table don't have an entry in its parent table

Comment: I take isschue with your spelling of "shedule". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a Cascade rule. It's working temporarily, but I don't know the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

> the insert statement conflicted with
>   the foreign key constraint sql server

Obviously, you're trying to insert some value into one of the foreign-key fields that isn't a valid value in the referenced table.

You say you have three columns - check each of those against the tables they reference - shouldn't be too hard to figure out which one is not valid - and then use a valid value instead. That's the whole point of referential integrity - make sure you don't insert invalid data into your tables!

Comment: But before that i am not able to add a single value in column Session in shedule table which is a primary key ,,is there any
settings i do here

Comment: @Peter: Can you show us the four tables involved, and how they're set up, and what exactly you're trying to do??

Answer (score 1):

The Error means what it says. That is, it doesn't have a column according to that id in a parent table.

To be more specific, please show us tables and INSERT statement.

**UPDATE:** If I got you right:

1) You try to INSERT a row into table **Shedule**, right?

If so, you need to have the **Employeeid** in table **Employee** and a **Topicid** in table **Topic**, that you're trying to INSERT.
I suppose, you don't have a valid Q&A foreign key value, according to error message. That means, the Q&A foreign key value you're trying to add in your INSERT statement must exist in Q&A Table.

2) You try to INSERT a row into table **Q&A**?

For this table you need to have valid **Employeeid** (2 of them?), **Topicid** and **Session_number**.

**P.S.** But I can't tell what's your problem if you don't show us INSERT statements.

Comment: But before that i am not able to add a single value in column Session in shedule table which is a primary key ,,is there any
settings i do here

Comment: @peter, if you have a foreign keys in Shedule table, you need to have values that you try to insert in the parent tables, before you insert a row. 
Can you, please, add table structures and insert statement?